# finding the path of a get request usering a re python

Tags: python, regex, string, get

well i want to create a http server using python 
so i handle the client and all of that stuff
and i want to get the path of the request using a regex
if the request is simple like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
OR
GET /TEST.PNG HTTP/1.1
```

so there is no problem getting a regex for that the regex is

```
"GET(.+)HTTP/1.1"
```

The problem is when there is parameters in the get request
like

```
GET /index?test=test HTTP/1.1
```

i have trouble to get only the path and a list of parameters using a re or ever other method really
the parameters can be all that come after the ? until the HTTP/1.1 and than use the split function with "&" so there more then one parameter to the request this is how i get a list of them but i have hard time fine the path and the parameters and separate them
thanks ahead to all the helpers and anyone that can help me with the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlparse` from the standard Python library.

```
import urlparse

http_request = 'GET /index?test=foo&bar=qux HTTP/1.1'
url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(http_request.split(' ')[1])
query_params = urlparse.parse_qs(url_parts.query)

# url_parts.path == '/index'
# query_params == {'test': ['foo'], 'bar': ['qux']}
```